# Rcpp or rdyncall

Tags: r, rcpp

I'm looking for some kind of references which explain the pro's en con's of using Rcpp when compared to using rdyncall.
Can someone who has used both explain the basic differences from an R package developers perspective who is interested in providing R wrappers to C++ code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think we mention rdyncall in the (brief) comparison to other approaches the intro vignette / JSS paper. It is a neat package, but aims for a much lower-level connection.  As I understand it, it gives you C-level APIs with least amount of fuzz, as motivated by say, the rgl package.  there is very good and detailed paper about rdyncall in a [recent R Journal issue](http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2012-1/RJournal_2012-1_Adler.pdf).

And unless I miss something, it does nothing for you on the C++ side.  Whereas Rcpp makes use as `.Call()` to pass complete R objects back and forth, and manages to map a wide variety of R and C++ types automatically for you---with the possibility add your own mappers.

Comment: So basically if I need to program some more things in C++, it would be better to use Rcpp and if I just need a simple C++ call, rdyncall would be the most easy?

Comment: Did you mean 'simple C call' for rdyncall? I think so---see the R Journal piece. And see our Rcpp documentation for help with it.